# Flutter List with background color shades in descending order

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

Attached is the screenshot of the problem I need to solve.

There is a simple list which needs to be color coded according to the priority.

The first list element will have highest priority with the darkest color shade and the color will fade with each list item traversed down.

I've tried making a separate list of variation of a color and using them by calling explicitly for ListTile background but it's not optimal for a list that can have infinite items.

I thought ColorTween may help but I'm still not able to figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using opacity or alpha option of Color, you can change background color.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 60,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        double opcaity = (1.0 - 0.01 * index) < 0 ? 0 : (1.0 - 0.01 * index);
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(opcaity),
              child: Text(
                '$index',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                  child: Text(
                    '0',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```